# why dont load the images for the first on my ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have a gallery slider in my project.

i have tested on my computer and all works fine,

but when i tested on my ipad the images for the gallery slider dont load when i open my project.

total images in the slider are 62 and have a total of 1.2mb

My Code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="fixed-bar" style="margin-top:40px">
        <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
            <li><a href="#p1"><img src="imagens/paginas/1.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#p2"><img src="imagens/paginas/2.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#p3"><img src="imagens/paginas/3.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#p4"><img src="imagens/paginas/4.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    $('.fixed-bar').hide();
});

$('#carousel').elastislide({
    minItems: 9
});
```

Preloader:

```
var images = new Array()
            function preload() {
                for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                    images[i] = new Image()
                    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
                }
            }
            preload(
                "imagens/Paginas/1.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/2.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/3.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/4.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/5.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/6.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/7.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/8.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/9.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/10.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/11.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/12.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/13.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/14.jpg",
                "imagens/Paginas/15.jpg"
 )
```

Comment: i don't know a what the problem could be or a solution, but if you have a mac you can use the dev tools of safari to access/debug the page on ipad the same way you would do on your desktop, probably this will help you to find the problem.

Comment: i have done some refreshes on my ipad. after 4 ou 5 times he loads the images.. in the console i have look but say anything about it

Comment: Have you checked webserver access logs to see if the images have been requested or not?

Comment: Loading 1.2mb of images is just too much for ipad. If its works after 4th try, its because then it using cached images. Try by loading only 3-4 images and for the rest use a kind of preloader

Comment: maybe is to much.. i try to use the preloader like the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem.

***what i have done:***

**Before:**
i had before one html document with several data-role="pages" and the first data-role="page" are my menu where the user can select the options.
When the user clicks on one of this options my code was `<a href="#p2"></a>` , the normal to go to the another page, (Note: only one of this options have to load the images in the gallery in the another page)

**After:**
And now, i have divide this document in two. One document html for only the start page (menu), and the rest of the several data-role="pages" in another document.

**How i have done the call:**

i use a popup with new functions and after the use select of one of this i had use this code:

```
<a href="../thisdocument.html" target="_parent"></a>
```

and the magic is done. without extra code etc....
only load the document html which contains the gallery slider from another sub-folder.

Answer (score 1):

Quick try: force the preload of all images. It seems that if your iPad render images at 4th or 5th try, it's because takes his time in load...

You can preload them with something like this:

```
var images = new Array()
            function preload() {
                for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                    images[i] = new Image()
                    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
                }
            }
            preload(
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg",
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-002.jpg",
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-003.jpg"
            )
```

I read the info in [this page](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/). There are also other methods to preload images.
I wish this help...

Comment: doesn´t work.. i dont know if i do this right.. i have try put this code in the head tag and try to put into the div of gallery slider..

Comment: i delete some images and tested only with 5 , but still not loading on my ipad

Comment: I took this example from the page I posted above, it's the 'JavaScript Method #1'. There, you can find the complete example, it seems that they put it in a simple `<div>`(inside `<script>`tags, of course ;] ). Anyhow, if this method doesn't work for you, you can find several methods in that page :)

Comment: Have you tested in other devices? Perhaps your iPad has low memory or low space in the MC... How did you tested, clearing cache or something? (Because if the fourth or fifth time effectively works...)

Comment: I haven´t tested in other device because the only i have. i have an IPad 3 with 16gb, and have a lot of space..i clear the cache every time after the test.. but i have solved it with another tecnic. and now it works..without preload javascript etc...

Comment: @user2232273 Glad to her it! :D Please, could you post an answer with your solution and auto-accept it? That helps other users that came here with your same issue... thanks!

Comment: arkana i posted.. if you like the question please rate it

Answer (score 0):

The limit for images loaded on iOS Safari is 3 MB for devices running on less than 256 MB RAM and 5 MB running on devices with more than 256 MB RAM.

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html